# Twitter API: Fetch tweets withing the last 4 hours

Tags: twitter

I have a small program that fetch tweets and displays them in google maps, it works perfect but I would like to know if there is a way to put a timeframe, for instance lets say I would like to fetch the tweets written in the last 4 hours, is it possible? Thanks for your help!

The program is written in PHP and javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using the `max_id` and `since_id` parameters. How you would calculate finding an `ID` within that 4 hour window, I am unsure, but this post might provide some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416836/5884189

Answer (score 0):

I just coded a solution to the same problem in a similar question. Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505038/php-twitter-api-search-tweets-get-tweets-from-last-hour-only/52392812#answer-52392812)  and change the `WINDOW` constant to `4` to get the tweets in the last four hours. Good luck!

PS: I think the mods don't want you to repeat similar answers in 2 questions so I let you the link, but I could edit the answer later and paste the code here if I'm wrong.